# Experience with two different display with effective DPI being same, differs

Tags: display, resolution, dpi, pixels

I have two display screens -

1. LG 22" monitor (22MP68VQ) which has a FullHD resolution (1920x1080) with DPI = 100. Contents are displayed without scaling.
2. Lenovo X1 carbon 6th gen laptop screen (14") with the FullHD resolution (1920x1080) with DPI = 157. However contents are displayed with 150% scaling. So essentially, the display layout after scaling becomes 1280x720 with DPI - 105.

As you can observe from the above data that the effective DPI are 100 and 105 respectively, which are almost same. However, the experience with the two displays are not same.
Having used both the displays at the same viewing distance, the texts on the laptop display (2) looks more smoother and doesnt cause strain on the eyes. But, if I spend my day with monitor display, I will have eye strain. However, if I use the monitor display with 125% zoom, then I wont have problem (effective DPI = 80).

If I could spend my day without eye strain on a laptop screen (2) with effective DPI of 105, then why would it hurt my eyes with a monitor screen (1) with DPI of 100; and I have to reduce it to 80 DPI to make it comfortable for me. Is DPI not the right parameter to consider to see what value would be comfortable for a person to view a screen at a given distance? If I have got misunderstood the concept please help me understand the concept rightly.
I am planning to buy a new monitor so understanding this would greatly help me in making right decision for new monitor.

Comment: Of course the text looks smoother on the display with the higher resolution. Scaling is applied on the text, not on the displayed image itself. Make sure the clear-type settings are correct for both monitors. If the cleartype-setting does not match the hardware of your monitor the result can get ugly.

Comment: Two questions - 
1. Why scaling is applied only the text and not on images?
2. How to make sure that the clear-type settings are correct for a given monitor?
(I have already followed these steps - https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/adjust-cleartype-windows-10. Do you mean some other procedure?)

Comment: You're comparing a 22" monitor with a 14" one and wondering why the smaller one is less clear at the same DPI? It should be obvious.

Comment: @DarshanL Please re-read my comment. I wasn't talking about images I was taking about the screen image as a whole.

Comment: @harrymc - No, I'm wondering why the bigger screen (22" monitor screen) is less clearer.

Comment: @Robert - If you are meaning the whole windows screen (say for instance the desktop screen), then I could see the icons on the desktops are also scaled bigger

Comment: Perhaps because the pixels are smeared a lot more.